# Help with DLL to Lib

Tags: c++, c, dll, static

I have converted a dll to lib. I gave it the lib and dll file and told it to remove the unnecessary stuff. I #included the .h file it created, and called GLU_DLLMAIN() in InitInstance just like I saw in the samples, but it still crahes on start up when it tries to initialize my static GLU object. What am I doing wrong? what is the proper way to do this to make sure I'm doing this right. Thanks

Comment: Err.. how are you doing that? AFAIK there is no supported way to convert a .dll into a .lib.

Comment: http://www.binary-soft.com/dll2lib/dll2lib.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary soft tool cannot so far as I can see work in all cases, so perhaps you have one of these fringe cases. On the other hand the .lib must be build with the same compiler settings as the executable to which is was linked, including assumptions about versions of standard libraries used.

Perhaps your issues are generated by mismatches between the compiler settings for your sample project and default settings on the conversion tools.